# Помогите найти адрес в памяти текущей страницы Google Chrome в windows XP

Tags: google-chrome, память, windows-xp

На Windows 10 я спокойно нашел адрес в памяти текущей страницы через Cheat Engine в Google Chrome.

Просто взял URL всех сайтов, которые на данный момент в браузере, начал открывать сайты и вводил их URL в Cheat Engine. Спокойно все получилось. 
Написал программу на c++ которая просто получала через память название открытой страницы.

Решил ее проверить в Windows XP, создал виртуальную машину, скачал Хром и начал искать тот же адрес, но ничего не нашел. Пошел по старой тактики открывал страницу и искал ее URL в Cheat Engine, но что-то ничего не вышло. Не могли бы вы мне помочь?

Comment: Windows XP??? Серьезно? Ее уже давно ни кто не поддерживает, зачем на ней тестировать софт?

Comment: @SnakeMS Мне нужно. Почему бы вместо этого не написать ответ, или вообще ничего не писать. Зачем высказывать свое мнение? Если я спросил, значит мне это нужно

Comment: @Log1c0 упрекать человека за мнение, то же самое что не давать ему возможности ответить. Некоторые комментарии, лучше оставлять в своих мыслях. Вот подумай, человек может и хотел помочь, но теперь пройдет мимо :( Насчёт XP он же ж прав, Microsoft давно её не поддерживает. С данной ОС понятие "безопасность" вообще очень растяжимое

Comment: А пробовал ставить более старые версии Chrome?

Comment: @L.F.C. Нет, а что?